# How BigInteger convert a byte array to number in Java?

Tags: java, byte, biginteger

I have this small code :

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    byte[] bytesArray = {7,34};
    BigInteger bytesTointeger= new BigInteger(bytesArray);
    System.out.println(bytesTointeger);

}
```

Output:`1826`

My question is what just happened how an array of bytes {7,34} converted into this number 1826 , what is the operation that caused this result ? like how to convert it manually

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The number 1826 is, in binary, `11100100010`.
If you split that in groups of 8 bits, you get the following:

`00000111 00100010`

Which are the numbers 7 and 34

Answer (score 0):

7 and 34 is converted to binary and give 00000111 and 00100010.After join it becomes 11100100010 which is in decimal 1826.

Answer (score 0):

As said, this creates a `BigDecimal` from its byte representation in [big-endian order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian).

If we used `long` to store result, manual conversion may look like the following:

```
long bytesToLong(byte[] bs) {
    long res = 0;
    for (byte b : bs) {
        res <<= 8;   // make room for next byte
        res |= b;    // append next byte
    }
    return res;
}
```

E. g.:

```
byte[] bs;    
bs = new byte[]{ 7, 34 };
assertEquals(new BigInteger(bs).longValue(), bytesToLong(bs));  // 1826
bs = new byte[]{ -1 };
assertEquals(new BigInteger(bs).longValue(), bytesToLong(bs));  // -1
```